# Reading url parameters in ruby/sinatra drops special characters?

Tags: ruby, url, sinatra, url-parameters

I have a url like the following:

`http://test.com:1111?langq=198&langname=C++`

When I read the params in ruby, `params[:langname]` gives me `C` and not `C++`.
Is there a simple way to stop ruby from doing this in this context?

Thanks.

Comment: You would have to encode the characters in the URL.

Answer (score 1):

This is an ongoing issue for Sinatra. See https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/search?q=plus

For now you will have to encode them.